# Asthma without coughing, wheezing, or chest tightness?

Tags: asthma, cough, tight-chest

Shortness of breath, coughing, wheezing, and chest tightness are the four classic symptoms associated with asthma. Is it possible for someone to not experience any of the last three symptoms and still be diagnosed with bronchial asthma?

Comment: Just as a n=1, I have been diagnosed with asthma and I have been asymptomatic my entire life. The only impact I've noticed is an occasional dry cough after extended maximal efforts (1/2 IM triathlons in heat) for 10-20 minutes.